# why datetime showed not like in the DB?

Tags: datetime, view, odoo, odoo-8, display

I've in the database the following lines

```
id |  date_order    |  name | origin

----+---------------------+----------+---------

38 | 2016-05-10 14:00:00 | OT/00024 | GI/00005:

39 | 2016-05-26 14:00:00 | OT/00025 | GI/00005:

40 | 2016-06-11 14:00:00 | OT/00026 | GI/00005:

41 | 2016-06-27 14:00:00 | OT/00027 | GI/00005:

42 | 2016-07-13 14:00:00 | OT/00028 | GI/00005:
```

but it showed in the views as:

```
date_order          |   name   | origin

--------------------+----------+-------------

10/05/2016 15:00:00 | OT/00024 | GI/00005:

26/05/2016 15:00:00 | OT/00025 | GI/00005:

11/06/2016 14:00:00 | OT/00026 | GI/00005:

27/06/2016 14:00:00 | OT/00027 | GI/00005:

13/07/2016 15:00:00 | OT/00028 | GI/00005:
```

I changed **Timezone but I still get the difference**  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo display the datetime field AS TIMEZONE, in this case the timezone is GMT+1 but it will be GMT+0 in june because of ramadan, that's why

Answer (score 2):

When you store the `datetime`, you should use context like this:

```
from openerp.osv import fields
from datetime import datetime
...
my_date = fields.datetime.context_timestamp(cr, uid, datetime.now(), context=context)
```

The date stored in the database is UTC (GMT-0) timezone. Assume that the person is set with timezone GMT - 5:00, then while storing the value to the database, the date will be added with 5 hrs (exactly 5, not little more or little less) and thus we get the UTC time to store into the database. Now when displaying the same it will check for the users timezone and it finds that its GMT - 5:00 so the database time will be subtracted with 5 (again exactly 5, not little more or little less) and displayed the user.

This will be great for system which is used in different timezones. So the understanding is the input is taken in the user's timezone stored in UTC(GMT-0) and displayed to user's timezone (even if the user viewing is in the different timezone the time will be accurate to their timezone)

Comment: cr, uid and context  are not defined

Comment: Of course, this is a part of code, it show how to use in a method! (So it is not a field definition)